# Importance of "_" in naming variables in SV

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have two different questions.

I was going through UVM source code UVM src/*.

I see the variables are name with "`_`" at so many places which are hard to read. Is there any importance for variables being declared in that fashion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `_name`, those are variables that you are *not* supposed to be using. Meaning, it's not part of the official API.